# Real Analysis Taylor Series Question!

Tags: real-analysis

Generate the Taylor coefficients for the exponential function $f(x)=e^x$, and then prove that the corresponding Taylor series converges uniformly to $e^x$ on any interval of the form $[-R, R]$. I'm still confused how do we use Taylor series to generate a function. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: I guess you want to find the Taylor serie of $f$ around $0$. Is that right ? A Taylor serie is a local object, so you need around which point you want to generate the Taylor serie.

Comment: You should have a formula for the coefficients of the Taylor series, in terms of the derivatives of $f(x)$. Fortunately, the derivatives of $e^x$ are easy to compute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula to obtain Taylor serie of $f$ around $0$ is :
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0) \, x^n}{n!}$$

But here your function $f$ is the exponential $e^x$ which has simple derivatives : $\forall n,f^{(n)}(x)=f(x)$. So the Taylor serie around $0$ is : $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^0 \, x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Now we need to compute the radius of convergence. So we apply the ratio test.

$$ \lim_{k \to \infty} \left |\frac{\frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}}{\frac{x^k}{k!}} \right | = \lim_{k \to \infty} \left |  \frac{x}{k+1} \right |=0$$

So the radius of convegence is infinite. So $\forall R$, the serie converges uniformly on $[-R,R]$.